# How do eclipse and intelliJ render fonts so differently?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, intellij-idea, fonts

And how do I get intelliJ rendering of the `ubuntu` font, on par??

I have eclipse perfectly using the Ubuntu font resulting in crisp, clear and properly kerned rendering, whereas intelliJ IDEA miserably renders the same named font on the same desktop.

The problem is mostly with the [kerning](https://www.google.com/?q=kerning), in the intelliJ redner the kerning is so terrible that ") are oddly squashed together:

[image]

I have looked at similar questions like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30750/why-does-the-monospace-font-look-great-in-terminal-and-gedit-and-terrible-in) which seem to be outdated or incorrect. Also the best answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/454361/font-in-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu-14-04 says "don't use in Ubuntu 14", which happens to be my OS.

Although `DejaVu Sans` kerns slightly less badly in intelliJ, it seems kerning has been really left broken for a long long while...

What might be the solution for intelliJ?

Comment: As for the »why« (which seems isn't actually your question here): Eclipse and IntelliJ use different technologies for rendering their UI: Eclipse uses native widgets and thus native font rendering via SWT, while IntelliJ uses Swing.

Comment: Thanks, I would never guess. If only intelliJ used SWT, it simply works well in this regard.

Comment: I'd say »if only Oracle fixed Swing's font rendering on Ubuntu« is a better wish to make, because that one's actually feasible.

Comment: Swing font rendering on Ubuntu being considerably worse than the other *nix flavors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is based on SWT toolkit which is a java wrapper around native UI components, in your case GTK.
IntelliJ is based on Swing and AWT thus rendering is based on whatever JDK implements itself. There are differences between OpenJDK and Oracle JDK and JDK prepared by JetBrains.

See [this discussion for IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-57233?_ga=2.49561766.100071332.1594249191-742097415.1594249191). In general, you might

- install another JDK (preferably one recommended by JetBrains)
- use JetBrains [new Mono font](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is a problem for me too. I can't fix it, but found tolerant variant for me:
Font: Anonymous Pro Bold 19pt.(Windows OS, but looks same as in Ubuntu) [image]

It looks still ugly, but better than stock fonts

Comment: Why? Your system does not support ttf fonts?

Comment: I Guess I should have said "where did you get that font?" as it's not present on my system. Anyway `Trebuchet MS` works sort of okay as well, I found now.

Comment: There is a post (but in Russian only) about fonts for programming http://habrahabr.ru/post/226637/
You can search these fonts by name and install in your system.

Comment: Thanks, I've given up on it, I find that `Trebuchent` works less miserably than the fonts above, which is a minor improvement I'll live with. Shame on intelliJ for not solving it for the common good yet..... :)